# Need to have duplicate item urls/GUIDs in RSS

Tags: url, rss, guid, podcast

I'm working on a tool to publish videos in a playlist, with the option to download as a podcast. Sometimes, items will need to be repeated over the course of the podcast. Having duplicate items or GUIDs causes problems though.

Does anyone know of a way to be able to have duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition `<guid>` have to be unique :) So there is probably no way of doing it that wouldn't cause issues with most agregators.